# exercising ARP on a page with plenty of items

Tags: oracle-apex, dml, oracle-apex-18.2

I have an apex form composed of around 50~ text fields and radio buttons.

I tried to create a page process for automated row processing. It works fine but only if my table has a column for each page item.

even though the page items are plenty, actually the question behind them is the same. So what I really want to perform is to collect those data row by row. i.e.

instead of

```
1      True    False   True      foo
```

I'd like to store my data like this

```
1        True         foo
2        True         goo
3        False        hoo
50       False        zoo
```

Since I couldn't find a way to *customize* ARP, I decided to do it with some manual work.

However I still have this feeling that my efort is futile. I can't help but thinking there must be some other, wiser solutions than being have to create insert/update statements for entire page. I mean I can't be the only one who came up with this need, right?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can have your own process that handles any data submitted, but have you tried interactive grids?

Comment: Hi,Yes, I did. But I have to abide a certain page design. 4 different pages, 12 items per page. I used wizard template to line the pages up. at the final page, by clicking finalize button, all the answers given are need to be stored at my table.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can achieve your requirement using `APEX_COLLECTION`. It stores the data temporarily that are associated with the session of the user currently logged into the application. below is the sample code for your reference.

```
begin
  if not apex_collection.collection_exists('SAMPLE_COLLECTION') then 
 APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => 'SAMPLE_COLLECTION');
  apex_collection.add_member(
    p_collection_name => 'SAMPLE_COLLECTION',
    p_c001 => :P1_TEST_ITEM1,
    p_c002 => :P1_TEST_ITEM2,
    p_c003 => :P1_TEST_ITEM3,
    p_c004 => :P1_TEST_ITEM4,
    p_c005 => :P1_TEST_ITEM5,
  );

 end if;
 end;
```

You can select the data stored using the below `SELECT` statement.

```
select  c001, c002,c003,c004, c005 
 from apex_collections where collection_name = 'SAMPLE_COLLECTION'
```

[Please refer this link to explore more on `APEX_COLLECTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531)